# Python: Class inherit

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is different between the two situation?

```
# Error: Cannot create a consistent method resolution order (MRO) for bases A, B
class A:
    pass

class B(A):
    pass

class C(A, B):
    pass

# Current situation
class A:
    pass

class B(A):
    pass

class C(B, A):
    pass
```

Comment: Answer should be in English.

Comment: OK, sorry for this.

Comment: I think you already wrote answer in first line of code.

Comment: Could you tell me some details or a link for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `C` is inheriting from `B` and `A`. Because `B` already inherits from `A` Python now cannot determine what class to look methods up on first; either `A`, or on `B`, which would override things defined in `A`.

You don't need to name all base classes of `B` here; just inherit from that one class:

```
class C(B):
    pass
```

`B` already includes `A`, you don't need to include it again.

**Updated Area:**

**Note:**

**To explain you in more details:**

Python needs to decide in which order to search through (direct and indirect) base classes when looking up an instance attribute / method. It does this by linearizing the inheritance graph, that is by converting the graph of base classes into a sequence, using an algorithm called [C3 or MRO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization). The MRO algorithm is the unique algorithm that achieves several desirable properties:

1. each ancestor class appears exactly once
2. a class always appears before its ancestor ("monotonicity")
3. direct parents of the same class should appear in the same order as they are listed in class definition ("consistent local precedence order")
4. if children of class A always appear before children of class B, then A should appear before B ("consistent extended precedence order")

With your code, the second constraint requires that `B` appears first; the third constraint requires that `A` appears first. Since there's no way to satisfy all constraints, python reports that your inheritance hierarchy is illegal.

This is not just a technical detail. In some (hopefully rare) cases, you might want to think about which class should be used to grab the method you called if the method is defined in multiple classes. The order in which you define base classes affects this choice.

Hope this helps you understand and helps you! :)
Thankyou!

Comment: But why the second answer is currect?

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you tell me more about monotonicity? I can't find any answer with searching. Why the class inheriting should abey monotonicity.

Comment: monotonic meaning that a class can be subclassed without affecting the precedence order of its parents. for more details and explanation see [this](https://medium.com/technology-nineleaps/python-method-resolution-order-4fd41d2fcc) or [this](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21659228/9400024)