# Multiple inheritance order in Python3/PyQt

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, multiple-inheritance

I met an issue when using multi inheritance with PyQt, the **Programe 1#** source code as below:

```
#!python3
import sys;
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *;
from PyQt5.QtGui import *;
from PyQt5.QtCore import *;

class WP_Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        print("WP_Widget init");
        super().__init__();

class WP_Line(QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self, text='',*args, **kargs):
        super().__init__();
        self.setText(text);

class Widget_C(WP_Widget, WP_Line):
#class Widget_C(WP_Line, WP_Widget):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Widget_C self = ', self)
        super().__init__();

class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__();
        fname = Widget_C();
        self.left = 100
        self.top = 100
        self.width = 100
        self.height = 100
        self.show();

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When execute, it will show the error as:

```
AttributeError: 'Widget_C' object has no attribute 'setText'
```

If change `Widget_C` definition 
from

```
class Widget_C(WP_Widget, WP_Line):
```

to

```
class Widget_C(WP_Line, WP_Widget):
```

**It will run successfully.**

I guess it will be related to **MRO** in Python3, so I write another **program 2#** to simulate the state:

```
#!python3

class QWidget():
    def __init__(self):
        print("Base QWidget init.");

class QLineEdit(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        print('LineEdit init');
        super().__init__();

    def setText(self, text):
        print('setText called');

class WP_Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        print('WP_Widget Init');
        super().__init__()

class WP_Line(QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self, text='',*args, **kargs):
        print('WP_Line init');
        super().__init__();
        self.setText(text)

class Widget_C(WP_Widget, WP_Line):
#class Widget_C(WP_Line, WP_Widget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

c_test = Widget_C()
```

But no matter which inheriting sequence of `Wiget_C`,

```
class Widget_C(WP_Line, WP_Widget):
```

or

```
class Widget_C(WP_Widget, WP_Line):
```

both of them will run normally.

So could anyone help:

1. Explain why **program 1#** fails when defined as `class Widget_C(WP_Widget, WP_Line):`, **MRO** is just my guess.
2. Why **program 2#** can be run normally in both condition ?
3. Help modify **program 2#** to reproduce the state of **program 1#** .

[Python and order of methods in multiple inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21657822/python-and-order-of-methods-in-multiple-inheritance) explains something about **MRO**, it related to my question, but not exactly the answer.
If inheriting order is the same, my **program 1#** and **program 2** should not have different results, so the key point is why **program 1#** and **program 2** have different phenomenon.

Comment: I don't know the details of the real `WP_Line` and `WP_Widget` classes, but I'd guess that one of them doesn't collaboratively call `super().__init__()` from its own `__init__` method, which means that the other part of the multiple inheritance never gets initialized properly. In your custom version, your classes *do* make appropriate `super` calls, so the issue doesn't occur.

Comment: QLineEdit inherits from QWidget, do you think it is necessary to inherit from QWidget if it already inherits from QLineEdit?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python and order of methods in multiple inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21657822/python-and-order-of-methods-in-multiple-inheritance)

Comment: @Blckknght Thanks for your reply, and I agree with your opinion, and If If my custom version works fine, this may be caused by PyQt ? I'm not sure.

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks for you help. QLineEdit inherits from QWidget is just a **custom test program** written by my own, not import from PyQt. In real case. It is not necessary to inherit from QWidget.

Comment: As [stated in the docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/gotchas.html#multiple-inheritance), pyqt does not support multiple inheritance of **qt** classes. Which is to say, it won't work the way you would normally expect it to in normal python. Having said that, [this blog post](http://trevorius.com/scrapbook/python/pyqt-multiple-inheritance/) has some interesting insights and work-arounds (but note that it was originally written for pyqt4, so some things may now be out of date). You should probably also [read this](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/multiinheritance.html).

Comment: @ekhumoro Thanks a lot, this is the exactly the answer what I expected. Maybe I should avoid using multiple inheritance with PyQt in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ekhumoro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/984421/ekhumoro) gave the exactly answer what I need.

As [stated in the docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/gotchas.html#multiple-inheritance), pyqt does not support multiple inheritance of qt classes. Which is to say, it won't work the way you would normally expect it to in normal python.

Having said that, [this blog post](http://trevorius.com/scrapbook/python/pyqt-multiple-inheritance/#comment-193111) has some interesting insights and work-arounds (but note that it was originally written for pyqt4, so some things may now be out of date).