# Extending two classes in another class?

Tags: python

Suppose you have two classes `x` and `y` and each has a `print` method. If you have another class `z` and extend both `x` and `y`, then if you call `print()` from class `z` what will be happen?

Comment: Why not trying it out?

Comment: Is the print method of both class x and y throw an error ?

Comment: What is class `c` (or is that a typo and you meant class `z`)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python and order of methods in multiple inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21657822/python-and-order-of-methods-in-multiple-inheritance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the order of classes matters.
If you write

```
class Z(X,Y)
```

then `my_print` method of class `X` will be executed.
and if you write `class Z(Y,X)` then `my_print` method of class `Y` will be executed.

note: there is built in `print()` function in python, please rename it. And class names should be Pascal case.

Example: this will output 'x':

```
class X:
    def my_print(self):
        print('x')

class Y:
    def my_print(self):
        print('y')

class Z(X, Y):
    pass

my_object = Z()
my_object.my_print()
```

and this will output 'y'

```
class X:
        def my_print(self):
            print('x')

    class Y:
        def my_print(self):
            print('y')

    class Z(Y, X):
        pass

    my_object = Z()
    my_object.my_print()
```

Comment: Is print method of both class x and y will throw an error ?

Answer (score 1):

Check this site:
https://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/multiple-inheritance/

And you are right, you separate with commas.